# Is the concept of spatial dimensions generalized beyound positive integers?

Tags: geometry

I can only find definitions of spaces, $\mathbb{R}^p$ where $p\in\mathbb{N}$ yet I cannot convince myself that having fractions of dimensions or even irrational amount of dimensions in a space would make sense or not. I.e how a sphere would look like in $2.5$ dimensions, how would we define distances, etc. Fractal dimensions do not seem to help, because as I see, they have a very narrow usage.(cannot define shapes or angles on them, or can we?)

*negative integer dimensions may be interesting too.*

Comment: What is your definition of dimension?

Comment: See [Hausdorff dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension), or just Google *fractional number of dimensions*.

Comment: Also see [Dragon Scales](http://youtu.be/Oc8sWN_jNF4) by Vi Hart for an entertaining introduction to fractional dimensions. Won't be much use if you are looking for defining shapes or angles, so I won't post this as an answer.